# Did I lose parquet files? Why isn't part-<file-number> incremental?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

I have a large (data) job, wrote the output to hdfs.  The parquet file output is not incremental.  The cluster later (I think) lost an executor, failing the job.

This is the output I see:

```
part-00004-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00024-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00051-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00057-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00064-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
...
```

This is the data I expected:

```
part-00001-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00002-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00003-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00004-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00005-762ce553-134d-4b3f-a2f8-4291baebfdb7-c000.snappy.parquet
...
```

Why isn't part- incremental?  Did I lose files?

Comment: have you tried reading the processed file and check the count?